# Запись таблицы в CSV c помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, csv

У меня есть HTML таблица, которую пользователи заполняют на странице, нужно что бы при добавлении данных на страницу, они дублировались в CSV файл, я нашла как каждый раз скачивать новый CSV, но не могу найти как записывать в имеющийся.

Вот JavaScript код, где я скачиваю файл, можно ли записывать это в уже существующий файл на моем компе ?

```
let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + '\uFEFF' + prob.map(e => e.join(";")).join("\n");
  
var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
alert(encodedUri);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
document.body.appendChild(link); 
link.click();
```

Помогите, пожалуйста)))

Comment: Браузер не имеет доступа к файлам. Вы можете конечно воспользоваться данным [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API) браузера, но оно поддерживается не везде, поэтому не думаю, что стоит его использовать.

Comment: @OliverPatterson если я прикреплю CSV файл, не знаю к странички в вк, например, или где то в другом месте. я могу его записать таким образом?